# Maximum execution time exceeded in required script file

Tags: php, execution-time

I have a script that is giving me execution time exceeded fatal error.
At first, the error was for my main script file. When I used ini_set to set the execution time for the script, that error went away but I got another execution time exceeded fatal error being thrown by another section...
The error says its coming from a required file that I `require_once` at the top of the script file.
However, the error is generated after an ajax call somewhere in the middle of the script file and the error calls out the first required file at line 4 of the script...

Error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in <b>[PATH]...\Header1.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

Top of my main script file:

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 100);
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\Header1.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\Require.php';
?>
```

Header1.php:

```
<?php
    if (session_id() === "") { session_start(); }

    $port_apache = "80";
```

I have tried placing ini_set() inside the header1 file on line 3 but then the error moves to line 3.

The header1 file only sets static variables, there are no functions, file includes, or anything else in there, so it is very confusing for me to see the error being thrown by something in that file.

What is going on?

Comment: Show the full content of failing script.

Comment: @EliasSoares I cannot and it would be many thousands of lines of code as well. Any ideas what might be affecting it and making it error in this way? I might be able to find snippets I can send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the max execution time limit in the function library files that the ajax call was posting to.